# Fetch GitHub source tarball without CORS issues

Tags: javascript, github, cors

Is it possible to download a tarball from a public GitHub repo directly in browser without CORS-proxying?

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vadimkantorov/torchwav/tarball/master')

/*Refused to connect to 'https://api.github.com/repos/vadimkantorov/torchwav/tarball/master' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src mc.admetrica.ru wss://webasr.voicetech.yandex.net mc.yandex.ru yandex.ru".

(anonymous) @ VM24:1
VM24:1 Refused to connect to 'https://api.github.com/repos/vadimkantorov/torchwav/tarball/master' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
(anonymous) @ VM24:1
Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at <anonymous>:1:1}
VM24:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at <anonymous>:1:1
*/

fetch('https://github.com/vadimkantorov/torchwav/archive/master.tar.gz')
/*VM52:1 Refused to connect to 'https://github.com/vadimkantorov/torchwav/archive/master.tar.gz' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src mc.admetrica.ru wss://webasr.voicetech.yandex.net mc.yandex.ru yandex.ru".
(anonymous) @ VM52:1
VM52:1 Refused to connect to 'https://github.com/vadimkantorov/torchwav/archive/master.tar.gz' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.*/
```

Comment: Have the "download" link access your node server, which fetches the tarball, and a send it back to your UI.

Comment: That's a valid solution, as is CORS proxying, but I wonder if there's another way around. Maybe, GitHub-specific? E.g. one could request all files individually via GitHub API, but it would be slow and eat API quota...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It isn't possible to do this in the frontend (that is, the browser), since the service that provides these archives doesn't support CORS.  You don't really want to download the same archive again and again for every user anyway, since (a) that's slow and a bad user experience and (b) GitHub may treat that as a DDoS and suspend your repository.  Having every user request every file via the API is similarly problematic and even slower.

You'll want to provide some sort of caching on the backend by downloading this archive once and providing access to the files you need via your app.  This is going to be a lot faster and result in a lot less bandwidth being used.  It also means that if the user reloads the page, they'll benefit from the caching that your app provides for the downloaded files instead of having to reload the same assets again.

Answer (score -1):

Just prepend the url with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

`fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.github.com/repos/vadimkantorov/torchwav/tarball/master')`

Comment: That's what I meant by CORS-proxying. I'd like to make my client-side app as private as possible and avoid letting users code go through intermediary proxies (especially for private repo tarballs case)

Comment: If it's public repository it doesn't matter. If it's private use your own server. You will not do that without proxy, because how browsers work.